# How to put a shell variable into a curl command in a shell script?

Tags: macos, shell, curl

I am trying to execute curl commands from my shell script on OSx el Capitan.
How can i pass a variable to the curl script. I tried this:
 `var ="some variable"`
 `curl -O '$var'`
But its not working. Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you also have space between `var` and `="some variable"` in your script? And what does *"its not working"* mean?

Comment: Yes its a long string of data and the variable changes everytime to give me a 200 OK , but it doesn't .

Answer (score 1):

Single quotes may be preventing interpolation of the variable.
Try this as a sample:

```
export var="http://www.google.com/"
curl "$var"
```

Comment: My bad am using a bunch of data not just the url so its curl -O --data 'random data=$var& some other data'

Comment: It's the same problem, regardless.  Your variable won't be interpolated inside single quotes; you need double ones to get anything except what you literally typed.

Comment: Thanks a ton will try this